# Why is my scroll eventListener not firing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, event-listener

I'm working on building a infinite scroll feature in an Angular app. Building one step at a time, currently I'm at the part where I attach an `eventListener` to the `#tags-panel-list` and need to check it's y position.

However the `eventListener` I'm using is not firing any basic `console.log`s.

**Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7OnKAGvVNXWLwN5fZqJu?p=preview**

---

**tagsPanel.html** markup:

```
<section id="tags-col" class="tag-column column">
    <ul id="tags-panel-list">
        <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">
          <div class="tag">{{tag.term}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**tagsPanelDirective** controller code (used `$timeout` incase Angular could not see the DOM element on first load):

```
var scrollingElement =  function(event) {
    // I do not see these console logs in the chrome dev inspector
    console.log('scrolling...');
    console.log(event);
};

$timeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('tags-panel-list').addEventListener('scroll', scrollingElement);
}, 250);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually the element with ID `tags-col` that is scrolling:

```
$timeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('tags-col').addEventListener('scroll', scrollingElement);
}, 250);
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/03FVi4qRIEPN82a8nbCU?p=preview)

Answer (score 12):

You can also listen to "wheel" on modern browsers. This will pick up the scroll regardless of element.

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: The `wheel` event is fired when a user scrolls on a mouse wheel or touchpad. It will not fire when a scroll is triggered from a key press or click on the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// only this work
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log(123);
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
})
```